# Почему выскакивает "This field is required"?

Tags: python, django

Ситуация - часть из `models.py` (модифицированый пример из туториала Джанги):

```
class Category(models.Model):
    cat_name = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.cat_name

class Poll(models.Model):

    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    close_date = models.DateTimeField('closing date')
    published = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question
    def was_published_today(self):
        return self.pub_date.date() == datetime.date.today()
```

часть из admin.py:

```
class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    list_filter = ['pub_date', 'published']
    search_fields = ['question']#, 'pub_date'   ]
    date_hierarchy = 'pub_date'

    fieldsets = [
    (None,               {'fields': ['question', 'published', 'category'] }),
    ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date', 'close_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]

    list_display = ('question', 'pub_date', 'close_date', 'was_published_today', 'published')
```

Добавляю в админке голосование. Заполняю все поля, но при сохранении показывает ошибку:

> "This field is required"

Для поля `question`, хотя я его заполнял.
Подскажите, что я неусмотрел.

Comment: Неужели ни у кого никаких мыслей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разобрался сам. Если кому интересно, был задействован тестовый мидлвар, который заменял "question" на другое значение.